# Child window does not get created

Tags: c++, oop, winapi

**EDIT** : Now this is strange, if I move the call to **jItems::populate ( std::string myList )** to the constructor of **jDropDown::jDropDown** from else where in the **jDropDown::jDropDown**, the child windows get created.

Originally its been called when the dropdown(jDropDown) window is made visible(shown), and the flow of the program doesn't allow a call to **jItems::populate ( std::string myList )** be moved to constructor of **jDropDown::jDropDown**.

---

What I an trying to do is create a custom Dropdown box from scratch, the problem I am facing is the final Items(jItem) windows are not created, its an oop design and
every Items(jItem) is derived from jPanel, the other parts of the dropdown box are also drived from jPanel so creating each and every window follows the same process yet the final
Items(jItem) windows are not created, they are not visible and I can't find them with visual studio Spy++

I have checked for instance handle and window handle, and both the checks returns true, yet the jItem windows are not visible and can't find them in spy++ (I can see all the other windows in spy++)

Any help is appreciated.

Here is a reference image and some relevant code.

[image]

```
bool jPanel::registered = false;


jPanel::jPanel( std::string txt, int x, int y, int width, int height, HWND parent, HINSTANCE hInstance, WORD bitmap, DWORD style ) 
                  : jControl( parent, hInstance, bitmap )
{


    if ( ! registered )
    {

        WNDCLASSEX wincl;

        wincl.hInstance         = hInstance;
        wincl.lpszClassName     = "jPanel";
        wincl.lpfnWndProc       = WndProc;
        wincl.style             = CS_BYTEALIGNWINDOW;
        wincl.cbSize            = sizeof ( WNDCLASSEX );
        wincl.hIcon             = 0;
        wincl.hIconSm           = 0;
        wincl.hCursor           = ::LoadCursor ( NULL, IDC_ARROW );
        wincl.lpszMenuName      = NULL;
        wincl.cbClsExtra        = 0;
        wincl.cbWndExtra        = 4;
        wincl.hbrBackground     = ::CreateSolidBrush ( backgroundColor );



        ::RegisterClassEx ( &wincl );


        jPanel::registered = true;

    }

    DWORD flag = WS_CLIPCHILDREN | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_CHILD;

    if ( style )    flag = flag | style;


    hwnd = ::CreateWindowEx ( 0, "jPanel", txt.c_str (  ), flag, x, y, width, height, parent, 0, hInstance, ( LPVOID ) this ) ;


};



jDropDown::jDropDown ( std::string txt, int x, int y, int width, int height, HWND parent, HINSTANCE hInstance, WORD bitmap )
                     : jPanel ( txt, x, y, width, height, parent, hInstance, bitmap ), capture ( false ), populated ( false )
{

    RECT rect;

    ::GetWindowRect ( hwnd, &rect );

    ::MapWindowPoints ( HWND_DESKTOP, ::GetParent ( parent ), ( LPPOINT ) &rect, 2 );


    items = new jItems ( "My Items List", rect.left, rect.top + height, width, 300, ::GetParent( parent ), hInstance, 0 );

    items->setBackgroundColor (  RGB ( 100, 100, 100 )  );

};




jItems::jItems ( std::string txt, int x, int y, int width, int height, HWND parent, HINSTANCE hInstance, WORD bitmap )
                     : jPanel ( txt, x, y, width, height, parent, hInstance, bitmap ), wWidth ( width ), wHeight ( 30 )
{

    ::SetWindowPos ( this->hwnd, HWND_TOP, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE );

};





bool jItems::populate ( std::string myList )
{



    int y = 0;
    Hinstance hInstance = ::GetModuleHandle ( NULL );


    std::vector < std::string >  list = model::Service::explode ( "^", myList );


    for (   std::vector < std::string >::const_iterator it = list.begin (  );       it != list.end (  );        ++it    )
    {

        std::string s = *it;


        jItem *i = new jItem ( "Your Item", 0, y, wWidth, wHeight, this->hwnd, hInstance, 0 );

    }


    ::SetWindowPos ( this->hwnd, HWND_TOP, 0, 0, wWidth, list.size (  ) * wHeight, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOZORDER );


    return true;

};



jItem::jItem ( std::string txt, int x, int y, int width, int height, HWND parent, HINSTANCE hInstance, WORD bitmap )
                     : jPanel ( txt, x, y, width, height, parent, hInstance, bitmap ), empty ( false )
{



    this->setBackgroundColor (  RGB ( 65, 65, 65 )  );



};
```

Comment: Check return value and call GetLastError on failure for every API call in the program. Without error handling you can only guess what happens here.

Comment: @AlexFarber that's the problem, the API isn't failing :(

Comment: If you want your child window to be visible pass the `WS_VISIBLE` window style to `CreateWindow[Ex]`.

Comment: @IInspectable I show the windows with ::ShowWindow() when required. The drop down shouldn't be visible when first created, only when user clicks on the DropDown. But that's not the problem, the windows are not getting created (I am assuming that's the case as I am not able to find them with spy++).

Comment: If the windows are not created then the return value of `CreateWindowEx` is `NULL`. If this is not the case and you cannot find them with Spy++ you probably messed up the window styles. `WS_CLIPCHILDREN` and `WS_CLIPSIBLINGS` are meaningful for parent windows. Don't specify them for child windows, **unless** they are parent windows themselves (i.e. they have child windows).

Comment: @IInspectable yes they have child windows. The annoying thing is that at other parts of the program, the child windows are getting created without problem.

Comment: Since this is a dropdown control you are probably missing a vital detail about the relationship between [child and parent windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632597.aspx#parent_owner_handle). In particular, a child window is clipped to the client area of its parent window. You cannot have a child window that extends outside the client area of its parent.